# How to re-size an image while display?

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, image-resizing

Is it possible to re-size an image while displaying an image in website?/ How to re-size an image after image been uploaded?

While adding i am uploading original image into original folder and creating 1 thumbnail  uploading into thumb folder. But in website i need to display images in so-many places with different dimension. So i need to re-size the images for required size to display to avoid image shrink.

or Should i need to create an image for all dimensions i needed while uploading?

Comment: "or Should i need to create an image for all dimensions i needed while uploading?" -- why not?

Comment: yes, prefer to resize/crop as many as the size you may use first, since it will be a heavy work load for apache.

Comment: Yes, do the resizing in the uploading stage.

Comment: I need totally 8 different dimensions of images, so should i need to create 8 folders and need to re-size for each dimensions while adding? I think we can re-size an image while display...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it is possible. Besides, it is, possibly, the best approach: to create necessary thumbnail images by request. If your website is in development stage you will never guess what dimensions will create the designer tomorrow. And you will return to your uploading function again and again to fit it for new design. It worth removing hard dependency between design and logic.

I'm not sure about codeignitor. Anyway, use something like this in your templates:

```
class Image {

    public $filename;
    public $caption;

    /**
     * Return full path to image.
     * @return string path to file to make thumb
     */
    public function fullPath() {
        return "data/files/{$this->filename}";
    }

    /**
     * Renders HTML IMG for thumb of given size.
     * 
     * @param int $width max width, set to -1, if not important
     * @param type $height max height, set to -1, if not important
     * @return string html tag for image with correct width and height attributes
     */
    public function htmlTag($width, $height) {
        $t = $this->getThumb($width, $height);
        return "<img src=\"{$t}\" alt=\"{$this->caption}\" width=\"{$width}\" height=\"{$height}\" />";
    }

    /**
     * Get/create thumb image
     * @param int $width width of the image
     * @param int $height height of the image
     * @return string path to the image
     */
    public function getThumb(&$width, &$height) {
        $currentImage = $this->fullPath();

        $thumbFilename = md5($this->path . $width . $height) . '.png';

        $thumbDir = 'data/thumbs/';
        $thumbFilename = "{$thumbDir}/{$thumbFilename}";

        // thumb already done?
        if (is_file($thumbFilename)) {
            // get real size to create correct html img tag
            if ($width<0 || $height<0) {
                $size = getimagesize($thumbFilename);
                $width = $size[0];
                $height = $size[1];
            }
            return $thumbFilename;
        }

        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($currentImage, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if ($ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'jpg') {
            $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($currentImage);
        } else if ($ext == 'gif') {
            $source = imagecreatefromgif($currentImage);
        } else if ($ext == 'png') {
            $source = imagecreatefrompng($currentImage);
        }

        $currentWidth = imagesx($source);
        $currentHeight = imagesy($source);

        // the sizes which we really will apply (default setup)
        $realWidth = $width;
        $realHeight = $height;
        $realX = 0;
        $realY = 0;

        // decide regarding cutting
        // if all params > 0, cuttin will be done
        $cut = FALSE;
        if ($width > 0 && $height > 0) {
            $cut = TRUE;
        } else if ($width < 0) { // width is not important, set proportion to that
            $width = $realWidth = round($currentWidth * $height / $currentHeight);
        } else if ($height < 0) { // height is not imporant
            $height = $realHeight = round($currentHeight * $width / $currentWidth);
        }

        if ($cut) {
            $kw = $currentWidth / $width;
            $kh = $currentHeight / $height;

            $k = $kw < $kh ? $kw : $kh;

            $realWidth = round($currentWidth / $k);
            $realHeight = round($currentHeight / $k);

            if ($kh < $kw) {
                $realX = round(($realWidth - $width) / 2) * $k;
            } else {
                $realY = round(($realHeight - $height) / 2) * $k;
            }
        }

        $virtual = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        imagealphablending($virtual, false);
        $col = imagecolorallocatealpha($virtual, 0, 0, 0, 127);
        imagefill($virtual, 0, 0, $col);
        imagesavealpha($virtual, true);

        imagecopyresampled($virtual, $source, 0, 0, $realX, $realY, $realWidth, $realHeight, $currentWidth, $currentHeight);

        // create file
        imagepng($virtual, $thumbFilename);

        return $thumbFilename;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$image = new Image();
$image->filename = "image.jpeg"; // really stored in 'data/files/image.jpg', let's say 300x400px
$image->caption = "My Image";

// get thumb 50x50: left and right parts of image will be cut off
echo $image->htmlTag(50, 50);

// get thumb of width 100 (height does not matter, keep proportions)
echo $image->htmlTag(100, -1);

// get thumb of height 100 (width does not matter, keep proportions)
echo $image->htmlTag(-1, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to re-size the image without shrink if you get the  height and width ratio and dynamically in the new height and width in the same ratio. But when you need small image if you load large image and using the height and width to display in small size. It is unnecessary loading time for the user.

Comment: So, any alternate solution for this?

Comment: Alternate is only making the thumbnail with different sizes. Otherwise you have to admit the website loading performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

Arun Jain's answers solves the technical/practical aspect of you question in a handy way.

More generally, when you deal with such computer intensive tasks, it is most of the time a good idea to do it the lazy way. At least from the CPU point of view.

The reason is that you never know whether a given image will be loaded at a given resolution *before* it actually is requested. Once it is requested, it is most of the time more expensive to re-compute it on each request than to store it for an hypothetical later use.
A common design is then to compute/resize the image when requested if not yet available in the cache and then to store for later use.

The timthumb library seems to handle all these points fine thought I've not used it myself.

I did some very basic checks in the library and it seems to have security in mind but I want to stress that it is advertised as beta software.